# Why do some identical POST requests take two or three times longer than others?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-multithreading

I want to send dozens of POST requests, each one separated by 50ms. All requests are identical. They take about 315 ms (send time + latency) but for one reason I ignore one request out of four (on average) takes two to three times longer (see Charles Proxy timeline chart below).

Can someone explain to me why? Is it because of a bad implementation of multi-threading (see code below)?

```
import thread
import time
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

url = XXX
req_data = XXX

session = requests.Session()
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
session.cookies.clear()

def send_request(url, data):
    r = session.post(url, verify=False, data=data)

for i in range(20):
    time.sleep(0.050)
    thread.start_new_thread( send_request, (url, req_data,) )
```

[image: Charles Request Timeline]

Legend from Charles documentation :

> Each bar on the chart is divided into three segments:
>
> - Request - the time spent sending (uploading) the request (dark blue)
> - Latency - the time spent waiting for network latency or processing    time on the server (mid blue)
> - Response - the time spent receiving (downloading) the response (light    blue)

**EDIT :**

**I analysed connections through Wireshark and below is an example of a ~300ms request and a ~800ms request.**

**It seems that the 800ms has two more ACK packets than the 300ms. Any one understands what is going on and what is different between these two requests ?**

*300 ms request*
[image: 300ms]

*800 ms request*
[image: 800ms]

Comment: why are you using threads?

Comment: I use threading to send a request before the previous one is finished. But honestly, I don't know if it is the good way. I am far from being a python expert.

Comment: do you need the results of that requests?

Comment: Yes I do. Each response is almost identical but I need a specific ID returned by the server in the response.

Comment: Looks like the server simply takes longer for some responses. There is nothing you can do in your client code to fix that.

Comment: @Tomalak, I don't think so. The variable part is the sending time (in dark blue).

Comment: Ah, I'm not familiar with the color coding in the diagram (you should add a screenshot that shows the key). I assumed that the dark blue was "waiting time" (i.e. time to first byte of the response) and the light blue was was the time until the response was complete.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I just added the legend from Charles documentation and updated the screenshot with the mouse hover tooltip.

Comment: Sending time is likely going to be dominated by the time it takes for the bytes to actually traverse across the network, and for the corresponding ACKs to come back. An HTTP request is small, often small enough to fit in one or two packets, so a large latency increase could be due to TCP retries due to dropped packets on the network. Or you might just have a congested network and some packets are taking a long time to arrive.

Comment: You might want to look at a thread pool for better threading implementation. Creating a new thread for each call seems wasteful. e.g `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool` or the `concurrent.futures` module have some threadpools available.

Comment: @DanielPryden Thanks for your comment, I analysed requests through Wireshark. I edited my post so you can see the results. I don't know why but the longer request has two ACK packets more.

Comment: @schlenk Ok thanks, I'll try to update my code by using a thread pool and I come back to update.

Comment: Are you sure that the server is taking the same amount of time for each request? Because if it's an issue with the server you cannot do anything about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packet analysis with Wireshark (see edit in the main post) shows that the 500ms gap between the two queries (a short and a long one) comes from the ACK packet at the time of SSL key exchange.

As a reminder, all my requests went through the proxy Charles Web Proxy.

After some tests, it seems that the problem lies in the SSL verification with Charles (which sometimes adds 500ms to the request uploading time).

**The queries have equivalent and regular sending times in the following cases:**

- **When I do not use the Charles Proxy**
- **When I use the proxy Charles but I go through "http" instead of
  "https" (No SSL)** (*this is my retained solution here because there is no sensitive
  data*).

Thanks for your help guys :)

*This answer shows link between SSL certification by Charles Web Proxy and the issue but doesn't explain it plently*